# how would i display json value by how high their number is

Tags: php

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "example": "1",
  "example2": 2,
  "text": "3",
  "info": {
    "agent": 4,
    "sum": 5,
    "collection": [
      {
        "Name": "6",
        "Pic": "7"
      },
      {
        "Name": "8",
        "Pic": "9"
      },
      {
        "Name": "10",
        "Pic": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I display the results of the JSON file in a foreach loop:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://linktojson.com'));
foreach($data->info->collection as $key){

    echo $key->Pic;
    echo $key->Name;

}
```

'Pic' has different numbers. How would I use `sort()` to make the largest number display at the top of the foreach loop and the lowest display at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort array values by custom criteria (before iterating the array with `foreach`):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://linktojson.com'));

usort($data->info->collection, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b->Pic - $a->Pic;
});

foreach($data->info->collection as $key) {
    echo $key->Pic, "\n";
    echo $key->Name, "\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

(Added newlines to make the output more readable.)

#### Output

```
11
10

9
8

7
6
```

Comment: Won't this only display Pic? What about Name?

Comment: i don't know why but this displays no results, while my original code does

Comment: @bobjomes This just sorts the data. It's entirely up to you how to iterate over it. Just use the `foreach` you already have.

Comment: i tried that, but it doesn't sort it. sorry, i'm new to this could you paste the whole code of what it should look like

Comment: usort($data->info->collection, function ($a, $b) {
    @return $b->Pic - $a->Pic;
});